# Update table set column = case when there is a duplicate found

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update a column in a table that would set to plus 1 if it can find a duplicate number in the column cownnum and else it would set to 1 if no duplicate was found

I tried the code below but show error

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 53
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.

```
update   dbo.temp1 set SEQNO = case SEQNO when (SELECT
    cownnum
FROM
    dbo.temp1
GROUP BY
    cownnum
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1) then SEQNO = 2 else  SEQNO = 1 end
```

for example the result would be

```
cownnum  1  1  2  3
SEQNO    1  2  1  1
```

Comment: Error clearly indicate that your subquery ("SELECT
        cownnum     FROM         dbo.temp1     GROUP BY         cownnum
    HAVING          COUNT(*) > 1"  returning more than 1 row which cause  the error. You should correct the query which return 1 row or you can use top 1...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` to check previous row value in `sqlserver`

```
Update temp1
set temp1.SEQNO = B.SEQNO
FROM temp1 A, (select id , COWNNUM, 
     case when COWNNUM = lag(COWNNUM) over(order by id) 
     then ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY COWNNUM ORDER BY id ) else 1 end as SEQNO 
     from temp1) B
WHERE A.id = B.id
```

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1964a3fefd77fd803ab3b26e342f263f)**

Comment: i tried your code but it gave me this error Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

Comment: updated answer by remove table variable and single update query

Comment: @ Triet Hoang, I have used rownumber() for auto set sequence numbers for each changed number block

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing, but there's no reason to use the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
    UPDATE dbo.temp1 SET SEQNO = 1 WHERE SEQNO = cownnum
```

or perhaps you need to check `cownnum` somehow:

```
   UPDATE dbo.temp1 SET SEQNO = 1 WHERE cownnum = (SELECT TOP 1 xxx FROM table WHERE ???)
```

Please provide an example of your data and the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.SEQNO = t2.rowno
FROM table_with_duplicates t1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT unique_id,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cownnum ORDER BY cownnum) AS rowno
        FROM table_with_duplicates
    ) t2
        ON t1.unique_id = t2.unique_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The perfect solution for your requirement is

```
UPDATE  @Temp1
SET     SEQNO = B.NewSEQ
FROM    @Temp1 A ,
        ( SELECT id,
            CASE WHEN COWNNUM = LAG(COWNNUM) OVER ( ORDER BY id ) THEN 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY COWNNUM ORDER BY id ) ELSE 1 END AS NewSEQ
        FROM    @temp1
        ) B
WHERE   A.id = B.id
```

you can check this query execution by clicking on **[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6ea655ff5992b0a0072d780f1cceee30)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions.  This is simplest using an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cownum order by (select null)) as new_seqno
      from dbo.temp1 t
     )
update toupdate
    set seqno = new_seqno;
```

If I understand the question correctly, no `join` is required.